# Are nameless parameters in main() strictly conforming?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, language-lawyer

C++ allows the following two definitions of main:

```
int main() { }
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { }
```

It also allows `char*[]` to be `char**` and `argc` and `argv` to be named whatever the programmer wishes. However, does it also allow:

```
int main(int, char*[]) { }
```

Is this identical to the above examples? Is it strictly conforming? Note, I don't care if it compiles in your favorite compiler, I'm asking about standards only.

Comment: Yes and yes. All C++ cares about is the _type_ of the parameters.

Comment: Even if it is valid, why would you want to? You can't *access* those variables without a name so you may as well just use the `int main()` variant.

Comment: @paxdiablo I do it to stop the compiler complaining about unused parameters because `argc` is not necessary for processing the `argv` (its *null terminated*). So I do `int main(int, char* argv[])`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as stated by @Captain Obvlious, C++ just cares about *type* of the parameters. C++ standard committee papers publicly available [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/) for your reference.

**3.6.1 Main function**

> 2. An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This
>    function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type
>    int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. **All
>    implementations shall allow both**
>
> — a function of () returning int and
>
> **— a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's quite valid.

First, `C++11 3.6.1 /2` states the allowable forms of `main()`, including the two canonical forms:

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. ***It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.*** All implementations shall
>   allow both of the following definitions of main:
>
> `int main() { /* ... */ }` and
>   `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }`

Then, in `C++11 8.3.5 Functions /11`, it states that parameter names are not actually *required* for function definitions:

> An identifier can ***optionally*** be provided as a parameter name; if present in a function definition (8.4), it names a parameter (sometimes called "formal argument").

However, given that the lack of names means that you can't *access* the variables, it's probably a better idea to just use the canonical form without them:

```
int main() { ... }
```

Comment: If you take it literally, the fact that identifiers are optional doesn't change that only the two given definitions of main are required. Or at least it's arguable and the wording should be improved